# Is it possible to measure function coverage with gcov?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, code-coverage, gcov

Currently we use gcov with our testing suite for Linux C++ application and it does a good job at measuring line coverage.

Can gcov produce function/method coverage report in addition to line coverage?

Looking at the parameters gcov accepts I do not think it is possible, but I may be missing something. Or, probably, is there any other tool that can produce function/method coverage report out of statistics generated by gcc?

**Update:** By function/method coverage I mean percentage of functions that get executed during tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess what you mean is the -f option, which will give you the percentage of lines covered per function. There is an interesting article about gcov at [Dr. Dobb's](http://www.ddj.com/development-tools/184401989) which might be helpful. If "man gcov" doesn't show the -f flag, check if you have a reasobably recent version of the gcc suite.

**Edit:** to get the percentage of functions not executed you can simply parse through the function coverage output, as 0.00% coverage should be pretty much equivalent to not called. This small script prints the percentage of functions not executed:

```
#!/bin/bash

if test -z "$1"
then
    echo "First argument must be function coverage file"
else
    notExecuted=`cat $1 | grep "^0.00%" | wc -l`
    executed=`cat $1 | grep -v "^0.00%" | wc -l`

    percentage=$(echo "scale=2; $notExecuted / ($notExecuted + $executed) * 100" |bc)

    echo $percentage
fi
```

Comment: -f option is not exactly what I want. It gives line coverage by function, but I want function/method coverage. I added clarification to the question.

Comment: Article is "gone", correct link is "https://www.drdobbs.com/code-coverage-for-c-unit-tests/184401989?queryText=gcov" but article is not showing. DDJ is dead. Here is a newer-ish article: https://medium.com/@naveen.maltesh/generating-code-coverage-report-using-gnu-gcov-lcov-ee54a4de3f11

Answer (score 7):

We have started to use gcov and [lcov](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php) together.  The results from lcov do include the percentage of functions that are executed for the "module" you're looking at.

**EDIT:** The *module* can go from directories down to files.

I also want to add that if you are already using the GNU compiler tools, then gcov/lcov won't be too difficult for you to get running and the results it produces are very impressive.

Answer (score 5):

The lcov utility is nice, and we use it. But I'm not sure if you need it for what you want.

We

1. Use ctags ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags); [sourceforge](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)) to find all the functions declared in the relevant header files.
2. Run GCOV to get line coverage for every function in the binary.
3. Compare the list of functions from 1 & 2 to produce "Functions Called" / "Functions Available".

We call it "API coverage" since we apply step #1 only to public API headers. But you can do it on all headers or only a subset as you choose. I think the ratio we produce in this manner is the ratio you are looking for.